# Скорость извлечения данных: структурированный текст или XML

Tags: c#

Как и из какого формата быстрее получить данные из структурированного текстового файла или из XML?

Предполагается, что в файле будет информация вида: параметр - значение.

Быстрее восстановить информацию в переменные из текстового файла с разделителями или используя xml формат?

В первом варианте планируется формат: `параметр<табуляция>значение<следующая строка>`

Во втором варианте - засунуть название параметра в node name, значение в attribute. Ну или параметр - в название атрибута, значение - в значение.

На мой взгляд, первый способ должен работать быстрее, т.к. количество данных по сути получается меньше, размер файла меньше, информация собирается за один проход по файлу последовательно. За xml я настолько не уверен.

А как вы считаете?

Comment: Реализовать оба варианта и замерять время на большом объеме данных. Дискутировать, что будет быстрее, можно бесконечно. )

Comment: ПРи больших объемах данных, чтобы твоя прога не сожрала всю память, и не вывалилась с OutOfMemory, нужно использовать потоковые парсеры

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем вопрос закрыт. Как оказалось, быстрее читать из текстового файла, но приходится заполнять свою структуру и с ней далее работать. Потому остановился на xml, для удобства использования в ущерб скорости.

Answer (score 2):

В общем случае, пока не определена структура данных, невозможно определить, что будет иметь выигрыш в скорости: XML или структурированный тест. И вообще говоря, XML - это тоже особым образом структурированный текст.

Если вся структура текста - это таблица с двумя столбцами ключ - значение, то она легко представляется в виде csv-файла. Если имена полей длинны, а значения коротки, то в этом случае, на больших объемах csv может иметь существенный выигрыш и в размере, и в скорости.

Comment: Спасибо, погляжу. Есть какой-то класс по работе с csv форматами в c#?

Comment: Нет, потому что это тривиально делается, если читать файл построчно с использованием `StreamReader`

Comment: @Modus, так а в чем тогда разница в скорости при работе с текстовым файлом структурированным самостоятельно путем разделения двух значений знаком табуляции и файлом csv, в котором тоже самое, только разделителем является комбинация "," ?